# Kivy, Python 3.8 - if-statement in canvas returns "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute"

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, attributeerror

I've created a Popup that opens when the game is finished, containing the high score, the current score and the amount of earned coins. When a new high score is achieved, the label score labels are changed from "Score: 10" to "New Best: 10 > 25" using an if-statement, with an icon above "new best" and an icon for ">", which are shown using canvas.after.

The if-statement works perfectly when used for changing the label text, but when used to change the canvas opacity/color it returns an AttributeError.

Here's the example code. Hopefully it's not too messy, I tried to clean it up as much as possible.

main.py:

```
# Using kivy 2.0.0 and Python 3.8

import kivy
from kivy.config import Config  # For setting height (19.5:9)
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ObjectProperty, BooleanProperty
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore

kivy.require('2.0.0')  # Version of Kivy)
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '360')  # (New Android smartphones e.g. OnePlus 7 series, iPhone X,
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '640')  # 11 and 12 series, upsampled)
store = JsonStore('user_data.json')  # For saving high score and wallet
root_widget = Builder.load_file('layout.kv')

# os.environ['KIVY_GL_BACKEND'] = 'angle_sdl2'  # If necessary, uncomment to prevent OpenGL error


class GameWidget(Screen):

    score = NumericProperty(0)  # Current score
    highscore = NumericProperty(store.get('highscore')['score'])  # High score
    old_highscore = NumericProperty(store.get('highscore')['score'])  # Previous high score for comparison
    broke_record = BooleanProperty(False)  # For checking if a new high score is achieved

    wallet = NumericProperty(store.get('wallet')['coins'])  # Amount of coins that user has collected
    wallet_label = ObjectProperty()  # In-game label where wallet is viewed
    old_wallet = wallet  # Used for count_coins() function

    coins = NumericProperty(0)  # Amount of coins earned in current level

    # Update the wallet
    def pay_coins(self):

        if self.game_finish:

            self.wallet += self.coins
            store.put("wallet", coins=self.wallet)
            self.wallet = store.get("wallet")["coins"]
            print("Wallet: %s" % self.wallet)
            self.old_wallet -= self.coins

    # Function to visually show the coins being added to the wallet
    def count_coins(self, dt):

        if self.coins >= 1:
            self.coins -= 1
            self.old_wallet += 1

    # Check if new high score is achieved
    def check_score(self):

        if self.score > self.highscore:
            store.put("highscore", score=self.score)
            self.highscore = store.get("highscore")["score"]

            self.broke_record = True

            print('new high!')
        else:
            self.broke_record = False

    # Reset all variables
    def reload(self):

        self.score = 0
        self.highscore = store.get("highscore")["score"]
        self.old_highscore = self.highscore
        self.broke_record = False

        self.wallet = store.get("wallet")["coins"]
        self.old_wallet = self.wallet

        self.coins = 0


class Menu(Screen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    WindowManager = WindowManager()

    def build(self):

        return self.WindowManager

MyApp().run()
```

layout.kv:

```
#: kivy 2.1.0
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
#: import Clock kivy.clock.Clock

<WindowManager>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    Menu:
        id: mainmenu
    GameWidget:
        id: gw



<Menu>:
    id: menu
    name: "first"
    orientation: 'vertical'
    size: root.width, root.height

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size


    Button:
        id: start_button
        text: "Start"
        font_size: 32
        on_press: app.root.ids.gw.reload()
        on_release: app.root.current = "second"
        size: root.width/2, root.height/12
        size_hint: None, None
        pos: root.width/4, root.height/2.5



<PopupFinish@Popup>
    auto_dismiss: False
    separator_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
    size_hint_y: .8
    size_hint_x: .9
    gw: app.root.ids.gw


    on_open: Clock.schedule_interval(app.root.ids.gw.count_coins, .01)
    on_dismiss: Clock.unschedule(app.root.ids.gw.count_coins)

    FloatLayout:
        size: app.root.size

        Label:
            text: str(root.gw.highscore)
            font_size: 48
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'y':.495}
            canvas.after:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1,1,1,1
                RoundedRectangle:
                    size: self.width*.1, self.height*.0625
                    pos: self.x*5.5, self.y*1.7979
                    source: 'resources/icons/crown.png'
        Label:
            text: "New Best!" if root.gw.broke_record==True else "Score:"
            valign: 'middle'
            font_size: 42
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'y':.255}
            canvas.after:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1 if root.gw.broke_record==True else 0, 0, 0, 0
                RoundedRectangle:
                    size: self.width*.1, self.height*.06125
                    pos: self.center_x*.922, self.y*2.25
                    source: 'resources/icons/crown.png'
        Label:
            text: ' {}     {}'.format(root.gw.old_highscore, root.gw.highscore) if root.gw.broke_record==True else "{}".format(root.gw.score)
            valign: 'middle'
            font_size: 57
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.475, 'y':.18}
            canvas.after:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1,1,1,1 if root.gw.broke_record==True else 0, 0, 0, 0
                RoundedRectangle:
                    size: self.width*.12, self.height*.05625
                    pos: self.center_x*.95, self.y*2.35
                    source: 'resources/icons/arrow.png'



        Label:
            text: '{}'.format(root.gw.coins)
            font_size: 42
            halign: 'left'
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.4, 'y':.0725}
            canvas.after:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1,1,1,1
                RoundedRectangle:
                    size: self.width*.08, self.height*.04
                    pos: self.center_x*1.125, self.y*3.03125
                    source: 'resources/icons/arrow.png'
                RoundedRectangle:
                    size: self.width*.08, self.height*.06125
                    pos: self.center_x*.725, self.y*2.9725
                    source: 'resources/icons/coins.png'


        Label:
            text: '  {}'.format(root.gw.old_wallet)
            font_size: 42
            halign: 'left'
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.7, 'y':.0725}
            canvas.after:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1,1,1,1
                RoundedRectangle:
                    size: self.width*.082, self.height*.06125
                    pos: self.x*2.25, self.y*2.98
                    source: 'resources/icons/coins.png'

        Button:
            on_release:root.dismiss(); app.root.current = 'first'
            size_hint: .2, .12
            pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'y':.05}


<GameWidget>:

    size: root.size
    pos: root.pos
    bg: self.bg
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: .5, .5, .5, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    name: "second"


    GridLayout:

        rows: 2
        cols: 3

        Label:
            text: 'coins: {}'.format(root.coins)

        Label:
            text: 'score: {}'.format(root.score)

        Label:
            text: 'high score: {}'.format(root.highscore)

        Button:
            text: 'score & coins +10'
            on_press: root.score += 10; root.coins += 10

        Button:
            text: 'score +100'
            on_press: root.score += 100

        Button:
            text: 'finish'
            on_press: root.check_score() ; Factory.PopupFinish().open()
```

user_data.json:

```
{"highscore": {"score": 0}, "wallet": {"coins": 0}}
```

AttributeError:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 242, in create_handler
     return eval(value, idmap), bound_list
   File "/Users/jessyliewes/Documents/Python/StackOverflow/highscore_menu_bug/layout.kv", line 89, in <module>
     rgba: 1,1,1,1 if root.gw.broke_record==True else 0, 0, 0, 0
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'broke_record'
 
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 924, in _build_canvas
     value, _ = create_handler(
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 245, in create_handler
     raise BuilderException(rule.ctx, rule.line,
 kivy.lang.builder.BuilderException: Parser: File "/Users/user/Documents/Python/StackOverflow/highscore_menu_bug/layout.kv", line 89:
 ...
      87:            canvas.after:
      88:                Color:
 >>   89:                    rgba: 1,1,1,1 if root.gw.broke_record==True else 0, 0, 0, 0
      90:                RoundedRectangle:
      91:                    size: self.width*.12, self.height*.05625
 ...
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'broke_record'
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 242, in create_handler
     return eval(value, idmap), bound_list
   File "/Users/user/Documents/Python/StackOverflow/highscore_menu_bug/layout.kv", line 89, in <module>
     rgba: 1,1,1,1 if root.gw.broke_record==True else 0, 0, 0, 0
 
 
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/user/Documents/Python/StackOverflow/highscore_menu_bug/main.py", line 93, in <module>
     MyApp().run()
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 955, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 570, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.mainloop()
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 335, in mainloop
     self.idle()
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 379, in idle
     self.dispatch_input()
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 330, in dispatch_input
     post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 263, in post_dispatch_input
     listener.dispatch('on_motion', etype, me)
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 731, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 1540, in on_motion
     self.dispatch('on_touch_down', me)
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 731, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 1557, in on_touch_down
     if w.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 731, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/uix/screenmanager.py", line 1205, in on_touch_down
     return super(ScreenManager, self).on_touch_down(touch)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 545, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 731, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/uix/relativelayout.py", line 297, in on_touch_down
     ret = super(RelativeLayout, self).on_touch_down(touch)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 545, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 731, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 545, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 731, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/uix/behaviors/button.py", line 151, in on_touch_down
     self.dispatch('on_press')
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 727, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1307, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1191, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 57, in custom_callback
     exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
   File "/Users/user/Documents/Python/StackOverflow/highscore_menu_bug/layout.kv", line 173, in <module>
     on_press: root.check_score() ; Factory.PopupFinish().open()
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/uix/modalview.py", line 195, in __init__
     super(ModalView, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/uix/anchorlayout.py", line 68, in __init__
     super(AnchorLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/uix/layout.py", line 76, in __init__
     super(Layout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 359, in __init__
     self.apply_class_lang_rules(
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 463, in apply_class_lang_rules
     Builder.apply(
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 542, in apply
     self._apply_rule(
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 664, in _apply_rule
     self._apply_rule(
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 664, in _apply_rule
     self._apply_rule(
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 605, in _apply_rule
     self._build_canvas(widget.canvas.after, widget,
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 930, in _build_canvas
     raise BuilderException(
 kivy.lang.builder.BuilderException: Parser: File "/Users/user/Documents/Python/StackOverflow/highscore_menu_bug/layout.kv", line 89:
 ...
      87:            canvas.after:
      88:                Color:
 >>   89:                    rgba: 1,1,1,1 if root.gw.broke_record==True else 0, 0, 0, 0
      90:                RoundedRectangle:
      91:                    size: self.width*.12, self.height*.05625
 ...
 BuilderException: Parser: File "/Users/user/Documents/Python/StackOverflow/highscore_menu_bug/layout.kv", line 89:
 ...
      87:            canvas.after:
      88:                Color:
 >>   89:                    rgba: 1,1,1,1 if root.gw.broke_record==True else 0, 0, 0, 0
      90:                RoundedRectangle:
      91:                    size: self.width*.12, self.height*.05625
 ...
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'broke_record'
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 242, in create_handler
     return eval(value, idmap), bound_list
   File "/Users/user/Documents/Python/StackOverflow/highscore_menu_bug/layout.kv", line 89, in <module>
     rgba: 1,1,1,1 if root.gw.broke_record==True else 0, 0, 0, 0
 
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 924, in _build_canvas
     value, _ = create_handler(
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 245, in create_handler
     raise BuilderException(rule.ctx, rule.line,
 

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if statements can only be used for certain things (label text being an example) in the kv file.

Assign the color to a property and then have a method that changes the property value, have this method called when you need the color changed...

Try

```
...
canvas.after:
    Color:
        rgba: app.Color
...

class MyApp(App):
    WindowManager = WindowManager()
    Color = ObjectProperty()


    def ChangeColor(self):
         if broke_record == True:
             self.color = [1,1,1,1]
         else:
             self.color = [0,0,0,0]
         #rewrite the if condition to suit your code
```

Comment: I was able to use if-statements in other parts of the code for changing canvas colors, but I tried your solution anyways. It still doesn't work. I also tried using `Color = ObjectProperty([0, 0, 0, 0])` and when I open the Popup, the canvas is invisible for a short moment but then it shows up again. I also added `print(self.gw.broke_record)` to on_open and on_close to check if there's something wrong with the boolean but False is printed both times.

Comment: Ok, sorry about that, I am not sure why but when you change to `'rgba: 1,1,1,1 if app.root.ids.gw.broke_record==True else 0, 0, 0,0` it stops throwing the error but the Label dosent seem to change color based on the if statement. I added two buttons to the pop up, one with `on_press: app.root.ids.gw.broke_record=False` and the other True so I could change the property while the popup was open and the colors didn't change... Dosent solve your problem but I though the idea of the two buttons to try and debug it would be helpful....